# How sort records based on two fields with different weighs of relevance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following example:

```
@ads = Ad.all
```

I need to sort by popularity so it is based on two integer columns: `contacts_count` and `visualizations`.

I want to know if there is any of these options:

1) List first the ads with the most number of contacts and to the records with `contacts_count = 0` show the records sorted by `visualizations` number.

2) Somehow attribute weighs to the two fields like: 5 to contacts and 3 to visualizations or something like that and sort by relevance by this.

How can I do this with active record or any search gem?

**schema.rb**

```
  create_table "ads", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "photo"
    t.text     "description"
    t.string   "category"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "visualizations",                           default: 0
    t.integer  "contacts_count",                           default: 0
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_ads_on_user_id", using: :btree
  end
```

Comment: Can you add the schema for Ads table, please?

Comment: hi @khaled_gomaa, yes sure I did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood from your description, what you need is not searching but sorting.

**Short answer:**

`@ads = Ad.order(:contacts_count, :visualization)`

**Wait but why?:**

> list first the ads with the most number of contacts

order first by `contacts`

> to the records with `contacts_count = 0` show the records sorted by `visualizations` number.

This statement is a bit inaccurate, you will use `visualizations` as a tiebreaker (even in the case of `contacts_count = 0` or just equal `contacts_count`.

Comment: It is strange that when I do Ads.all.order(:contacts, :visualizations) or even Ads.all.order(:contacts) it returns nothing

Comment: can you attach screenshots so I can debug with you?

Comment: Sorry my fault was that the column was named 'contacts_count' and not 'contacts' it works now.